# join objects in list with enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently searching and returning results from 3 different databases using MVC. The results from each DB are placed into a single set of `SoftwareLight` objects that contain common fields from all DBs, as well as a `Context` property to indicate which DB the result comes from. That part works great so far.

Now what I am looking to do is to combine each `SoftwareLight` objects that have the same name but come from a different context into a single entry. Ideally the `Context` property of this "merged" entry would also hold all of the contexts where it was found...

To give you a small example of what these result sets might look like, and what I'd like to ultimately achieve, please see below. But mainly, my questions are the following:

1. How can I make the `Context` property accept multiple enum entries at once? (I've seen this done using a single `&` or single `|` and later checked against using the `Enum.HasFlag();` method?)
2. How can I efficiently combine/merge the results that have the same name into a single entry?

[**EDIT**] As requested, I have added the SoftwareLight class and the Context enum declaration.

```
 public class SoftwareLight : IEquatable<SoftwareLight>
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public int? Installs { get; set; }
    public AppContext Context { get; set; }
    public bool External { get; set; }
 }

[Flags]
public enum AppContext
{
    NET,
    LOCAL,
    LICENSES
}
```

Example of **current** search code:

```
        //Current searching method...
        NET_DATA db1 = new Model.NET_DATA();
        LOCAL_DATA db2 = new Model.LOCAL_DATA();
        LICENSING_DATA db3 = new Model.LICENSING_DATA();

        List<SoftwareLight> finds = new List<SoftwareLight>();

        //SoftwareLight items returned have their Context Property set to 'NET'
        finds.AddRange(db1.Find(searchterms));
        //SoftwareLight items returned have their Context Property set to 'LOCAL'
        finds.AddRange(db2.Find(searchterms));
        //SoftwareLight items returned have their Context Property set to 'LICENSES'
        finds.AddRange(db3.Find(searchterms));

        finds = finds.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();

        //HOW DO I COMBINE THEM HERE?
```

Example of **current** results, searching for the term "Dreamweaver":

```
    |---------------------------------------------------------|
    | Product Name      | Context  | Public Facing | Installs |
    |---------------------------------------------------------|
    | Adobe Dreamweaver | NET      | No            | 23       |
    |---------------------------------------------------------|
    | Adobe Dreamweaver | LOCAL    | No            | 7        |
    |---------------------------------------------------------|
    | Adobe Dreamweaver | LICENSES | No            | 9        |
    |---------------------------------------------------------|
```

Example of **wanted** results, searching for the term Dreamweaver:

```
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
    | Product Name      | Context              | Public Facing | Installs |
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
    | Adobe Dreamweaver | NET, LOCAL, LICENSES | No            | 39       |
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question, by (1) providing the declaration of the `SoftwareLight` class and (2) Specifying if it is possible that "Adobe Dreamweaver" with context "NET" has "Public Facing" = No, but with context "LOCAL" has "Public Facing" = Yes?

Comment: The information requested has been added to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you need to `GroupBy` instead of `OrderBy`.

So instead of doing

```
finds = finds.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
```

You should do something like this:

```
var myGroups = finds
   .GroupBy(a => a.Name)
   .Select(g => new SoftwareLight() {
        Name = g.Key,
        // What should be done with the version field?
        // Right now, I am concatenating distinct versions.
        Version = string.Join(", ", g.Select(v => v.Version).Distinct()),
        // "OR" through aggregation.
        Context = g.Aggregate((AppContext)0, (c, v) => (AppContext)(c | v.Context)),
        // True if any is public facing
        External = g.Any(v => v.External),
        Installs = g.Sum(v => v.Installs))
    });
```

Comment: i will take a look... this answers the merging question, but not the enum one since you're putting the results into a list... i would like to re-use the `SoftwareLight` object and have the Context be a single enum instead of a list... i will test this out and let you know though. As far as the rest of the fields are concerned, I have requirements for those so it's not a problem. :) But good catch! :)

Comment: Ok. As requested, can you provide an answer to the two questions, then I could update this answer accordingly.

Comment: PublicFacing needs to be "if any are true, then true"... what`s the second question?

Comment: Updated with your new information. The second question was: can you provide the code for the `SoftwareLight` class, including the `Context` enum.

Answer (score 0):

Since the flags are just integers, you can easily sum them up in an group clause.

Assuming your Context looks like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Context
{
    NET = 1,
    LOCAL = 2,
    LICENSES = 4
}

public class Product
{
    public Context Context;
    public string Name;
}

Product[] items = new[]
{
    new Product { Name = "Adobe", Context = Context.NET },
    new Product { Name = "Adobe", Context = Context.LICENSES },
    new Product { Name = "Adobe", Context = Context.LOCAL },
    new Product { Name = "Adobe2", Context = Context.LOCAL },
    new Product { Name = "Adobe2", Context = Context.NET }
};
```

you can use this statement to actually get the combined enum:

```
var result = from item in items
    group item by item.Name
    into itemGroup
    select new
    {
        itemGroup.Key,
        Context = (Context)itemGroup.Sum(x => (int)x.Context)
    };
```